# Spark saveToEs asynchronously

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-spark, spark-streaming

We have a spark streaming job which writes output to ElasticSearch. When elasticsearch is slow due to any reason, spark job waits indefinitely which causes it to accumulate data and has a snowballing effect on the streaming job itself. The only solution to make the streaming job stable then is to restart it.

Is there a way to specify spark writes to elastic search to be asynchronous? I tried looking at https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/hadoop/current/configuration.html and do not see any option to have async writes.

Comment: I could be wrong but and I don't think that asynchronous writes can help you here. This won't release resources required to process the next batch so Spark will wait anyway before starting the next batch.

Comment: If not for the write acknowledgement, what would the spark resources be held up for?

Comment: It is not exactly my point. If your goal is to simply fire and forget then you can always use `mapPartitions` for that. But if you're actually interested if writes succeed then executor thread will have wait. I mean when task is finished then its context is gone.

Comment: I am ok with fire and forget and have no business logic based on whether writes succeeded or not (I hope it succeeds though) but the default behavior seems to be wait for successful write. I have the EsSpark.saveToEs invocation in DStream.ForeachRDD. Not exactly mapPartitions. It should still behave the same way w.r.t ES writes correct?

Comment: Yes. I mean some like  `stream.foreachRDD(rdd => rdd.foreachPartition(iter => yourMethodToWriteAsync))`

Comment: I only use           EsSpark.saveToEs(df, customer+DateFunctions.dateNow()+ "/" + processingDoc)         I am not sure how to write this method you mentioned- yourMethodToWriteAsync and that is my question.

Comment: @SunitaKoppar: Can you share your code snippet. I am also trying to do same thing. To push data from spark to ES. I dont know where to specify the ip address of elasticsearch which is running? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @YogeshDarji, This is how I do it:                                                           val sparkConf: SparkConf = new SparkConf().
      setAppName(s"MyApp [bucket_${bucketDurSec}s, sliding_${slidingDurSec}s, batch_${batchDurSec}s}]").
      set("es.nodes", "localhost") . Our actual app has an interface ConfigurationOptions where default values for es.host, es.port etc are defined. If you need bare minimum settings, this approach should work